# unable to change class of li element on clicking it in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

i have currently included the following in my application.html.erb

```
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'customjsFile', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true  %>
```

and placed my javascript 'customjsFile' in '/app/assets//javascripts' folder.

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="http://localhost:3000/home" onclick="f1()">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://localhost:3000/contests">CONTESTS</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://localhost:3000/professors">PROFESSORS</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://localhost:3000/challenges">BLOG</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost:3000/about">ABOUT</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
```

now i want to remove the existing 'active' class and add 'active' class to the clicked on li element.
I added the following code in my customjsFile

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.nav li a').click(function(e) {
        alert("Clicked");
        $('.nav li').removeClass('active');

        var $parent = $(this).parent();
        if (!$parent.hasClass('active')) {
            $parent.addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

but on clicking the 'li' element it's not getting redirected to 'href' of 'a' tag
i tried adding the following code to customjsFile.js

```
$(document).on("click", "a", function(){
    window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');

});
```

but then i am redirected to 'href' of the clicked 'a' element but my active class doesn't change to the clicked 'li'  but rather remains the same

Answer (score 0):

You should listen to `page:change` event, becuase you are using turbolinks:

```
$(document).on('page:change', function () {
  $('.nav li a').click(function(e) {
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do: `$('.nav li').removeClass('active');`, it means you select all the elements with class name `nav` and that contains an `<li>` and you remove the class name `active` from them.

I suspect what you need is to remove the class name `active` only from the current clicked element, and so use `$(this)`:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.nav li a').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $parent = $(this).parent();
            $parent.removeClass('active');

});
```

Note:  Do not forget to prevent default behaviour of anchor. and i think your `li` element should have an initial class name apart from `active`. Try also to read about `.toggleClass()`